# Is there a sequence that converges in $L^{1}[0,1]$ but not $L^{2}[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

> Is there a sequence that converges in  $L^{1}[0,1]$ but not $L^{2}[0,1]$?

For some sequence of integrable functions $f_{n}$, I am not sure how the integrals $\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}(x)|^{2}dx$ and $\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}(x)|dx$ relate to each other. 
Would $\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}(x)|dx\to 0 $ necessarily imply $\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}(x)|^{2}dx\to 0$?

Also, if I remember correctly, there was some subset relation between convergence of functions in $L^{p}$ and convergence of sequences in $\ell^{p}$ for increasing/decreasing values of integers $p$ - would someone be able to link me to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f_n(x)=\sqrt n $ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac 1 n$ and $0$ for $x >\frac 1 n$.

Comment: If you use $0<x\leq\frac1n$, they also converge pointwise.

Comment: When we are talking about convergence in $L^{p}$ spaces we don't care about convergence/divergence on sets of measure $0$.

Comment: I didn't say your answer was wrong. Just pointing out that it's possible, without too much change, to make your sequence converge pointwise. Some people may find that a more pleasing example.